# Send Push Notification every time Data Browser changes

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I have a chat that uses Parse.com to store messages.

How can I send a Push Notification every time a row has been added to a custom class called `Chat`? Is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the send code when you add your row.

There are a lot of tutorial about sending push notification, especially with a chat as example.
For example here : http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Self-Edit : Fixed bad link

Comment: I have checked that link and there is no mention of sending push notification. Are you sure that was the tutorial you wanted to show?

Comment: Yeah, I think I did not thought about sending it together with the ``PFObject``. That would make the push notification even quicker, i suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out parse.com cloud code guide, specially the part: [Performing actions after a save](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave)

Also check out the send push notifications section.

Basically you can setup a method to be triggered everytime a chat is saved. This code will run automatically on parse servers.